# How to include a library in CMakeLists

Tags: catkin-make, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What's the proper way to include external libraries in a C++ ROS package?

I've written a C++ program that reads data from an I2C device using the [I2Cdevlib](https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib), and now I'm trying to re-package it as a ROS node and build it via catkin.

I'm building the non-catkin code via:

```
gcc -o mpu6050_reader ${PATH_I2CDEVLIB}RaspberryPi_bcm2835/MPU6050/examples/MPU6050_example_1.cpp \
 -I ${PATH_I2CDEVLIB}RaspberryPi_bcm2835/I2Cdev ${PATH_I2CDEVLIB}RaspberryPi_bcm2835/I2Cdev/I2Cdev.cpp \
 -I ${PATH_I2CDEVLIB}Arduino/MPU6050/ ${PATH_I2CDEVLIB}Arduino/MPU6050/MPU6050.cpp -l bcm2835 -l m
```

I've initialized a C++ ROS package, and refactored MPU6050_example_1.cpp into the ROS-equivalent mpu6050_node.cpp, and now I'm trying to translate the above call to CMakeLists.txt so it compiles with `catkin_make`. What's the best way to do this?

Should I include the i2cdevlib and bcm2835 libraries in my package, or require the user to download and install them separately?

I've read through the documentation on [CMakeLists.txt](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt), but it's unclear to me which parameters I should use. Should I use `add_library()` or `include_directories()` or `add_dependencies()` or `target_link_libraries()`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239690/how-to-include-a-library-in-cmakelists/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2016-07-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

compile your i2c library similar to

```
add_library(mylib src/mylib.cpp)
```

then compile your node then link your library to your node

```
add_executable(mynode src/mynode.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mynode mylib)
```

If it is an external library

```
find_package( PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules( mylib REQUIRED mylib )
```

or

```
FIND_LIBRARY(mylib_LIBRARIES mylib /path/to/lib)
```

then link the library to your node

```
add_executable(mynode src/mynode.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mynode ${mylib_LIBRARIES})
```

hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2016-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9